# Latex Table - \smallskip breaks vertical lines

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I am creating a table, in which I want to separate groups of lines, using `\smallskip`. However, at the very left of the table there is a `\multirow` cell, whose vertical lines are now broken.

Is there a nice solution for this?
Resulting image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % define this before the line numbering.
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\mainmatter
    \begin{table}[t]    
        \footnotesize 
        \begin{center}
            \label{table:Sequences}
            \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt} 
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \cline{5-5}
                \cline{5-5}
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{blah}}\\
                \cline{5-5}
                \noalign{\smallskip}
                \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}
                \multirow{11}{*}{\centering\begin{turn}{90}\textit{Broken Multirow}\end{turn}  } & {} & \multirow{3}{*}{\centering\begin{turn}{90}\textit{a}\end{turn}   }      & {} & { $1$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}      & {} & { $2$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}      & {} & { $3$ } \\   \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}\noalign{\smallskip}
                                                                                                            \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} & \multirow{3}{*}{\centering\begin{turn}{90}\textit{b}\end{turn}     }  & {} & { $1$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $2$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $3$ } \\   \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}\noalign{\smallskip}
                                                                                                            \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} & \multirow{3}{*}{\centering\begin{turn}{90}\textit{c}\end{turn}     }  & {} & { $1$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $2$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $3$ } \\   \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}\noalign{\smallskip}
                                                                                                            \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} & \multirow{3}{*}{\centering\begin{turn}{90}\textit{d}\end{turn}     }  & {} & { $1$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $2$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $3$ } \\   \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}
                \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\mainmatter
    \begin{table}[t]    
        \footnotesize 
        \begin{center}
            \label{table:Sequences}
            \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt} 
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \cline{5-5}
                \cline{5-5}
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{blah}}\\
                \cline{5-5}
                \noalign{\smallskip}
                \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}
                \multirow{11}{*}{\centering\begin{turn}{90}\textit{Broken Multirow}\end{turn}  } & {} & \multirow{3}{*}{\centering\begin{turn}{90}\textit{a}\end{turn}   }      & {} & { $1$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}      & {} & { $2$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}      & {} & { $3$ } \\   \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}\noalign{\smallskip}
                                                                                                            \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} & \multirow{3}{*}{\centering\begin{turn}{90}\textit{b}\end{turn}     }  & {} & { $1$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $2$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $3$ } \\   \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}\noalign{\smallskip}
                                                                                                            \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} & \multirow{3}{*}{\centering\begin{turn}{90}\textit{c}\end{turn}     }  & {} & { $1$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $2$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $3$ } \\   \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}\noalign{\smallskip}
                                                                                                            \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} & \multirow{3}{*}{\centering\begin{turn}{90}\textit{d}\end{turn}     }  & {} & { $1$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $2$ } \\           \cline{5-5}
                                                    {} & {} &                                   {}  & {} & { $3$ } \\   \cline{3-3}     \cline{5-5}
                \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}\cline{5-5}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). t would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: If you load `array`, you can specify `extrarowheight`. Maybe that would work better?

Comment: As requested, minimal example added. I tried with `extrarowheight` but without much success I have to admit.

Comment: Instead of `\noalign{\smallskip}`, use `\\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\smallskipamount]`.

Comment: @Werner: It works! If you want you can post this as an answer and I will accept this. After this I will post a full compile-able code snippet.

Comment: @dim_tz: Using `\\[<len>]` like I suggested is a dirty trick, since you still create a full-height row that is just shifted up by the appropriate amount. [`hhline`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) provides this type of functionality in a more natural way by drawing the rules in the "correct" way. You should also consider a [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) approach.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use \smallskip, but the `hhline` package instead, and `makecell` to ease the formatting of multirow cells:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{heuristica} 

    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{hhline}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[6pt]}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\itshape}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{tabular}{*{3}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}|}}
    \hhline{|-||-||-|}
    \multirowthead{9}[-0.5\baselineskip]{\rotatebox{90}{\itshape Unbroken Multirow}} &\multirowthead{3}{\rotatebox{90}{Set 1}} & A1 \\%
    \cline{3-3}
        & & B1 \\
    \cline{3-3}
        & & C1 \\
    \hhline{|~|:=::=:} 
    &\multirowthead{3}{\rotatebox{90}{Set 2}} & A2 \\
    \cline{3-3}
        & & B2 \\
    \cline{3-3}
        & & C2 \\
    \hhline{|~|:=::=:} 
    &\multirowthead{3}{\rotatebox{90}{Set 3}} & A3 \\
    \cline{3-3}
        & & B3 \\
    \cline{3-3}
        & &C3 \\
    \hhline{|-||-||-|}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hm, actually the `=` in the `\hhline` gives a black gap between the "sets", while in your case output is different. Any idea? I do not use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage{heuristica}`, as I get errors.

Comment: You probably get errors because your source file is not UTF8 encoded. Note that TeXMaker can convert to UTF8 — provided you know the actual encoding. Any way this is not related to the font :  I tried Computer Modern, Latin Modern and Minion Pro, always without any black gap. Wouldn't that be a problem  of your viewer?